# How to generate an executable file for Linux on Windows?

Tags: linux, x86, embedded

I have an x86 development board with Linux running on it, but I don't know how to develop an application for it, from my PC with Windows.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You also need to get basic Linux programming skills and mindset. I suggest installing a real Linux system on your development PC.

Comment: What does the development board's manufacturer say ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Cygwin and install GCC on it !

Comment: The original poster wants to produce Linux/x86 executables. Using cygwin to cross-compile GCC is then not enough. You'll need to configure, cross-compile, install the entire build chain (which means more that just GCC, but also Binutils, Glibc, etc.etc..)

Comment: Lots of post on the internet say that you only need crosstools to compile for Linux. Such as http://metamod-p.sourceforge.net/cross-compiling.on.windows.for.linux.html. Am I wrong ?

Comment: But the original poster wants to "develop an application" for his "embedded Linux board...."

Comment: The poster may be cross compiling anyway, even if doing so from a desktop linux since it may not be the same x86 linux as the target.  Cygwin or Mingw solutions are possible as cross compile hosts, but more painful to configure due to wierdness and slower to run (ie to compile target programs) due to fork behavior emulation.  If the target is close enough to an incumbent normal desktop linux that cross compiling is not required, then an existing cross compiler for cygwin/mingw targeting normal x86 linux may well work.

Comment: thank you, i will try to follow [link](http://metamod-p.sourceforge.net/cross-compiling.on.windows.for.linux.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use a virtualization software like [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) to run Linux as a guest operating system in your windows machine. You can then create all your executable in the guest machine for your development board.

Comment: thanks, but i don't have enough time to study Linux programming.

Comment: @YangH You don't have to study Linux programming for running a Linux environment on Virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a network connection to the development board?

You can just remotely build and test your application on the target via SSH. Many IDE's like eclipse support that seamlessly.

This is a lot better as you get the exact same build environment as your target linux distro as well as the real-time characteristics of your target system.

Answer (score 0):

You can write code on your (Windows) development PC, but to build executable binaries for Linux you'll need to be compiling on the Linux box.  That also means that you might need to be writing in a cross-platform language (perhaps C++, Qt or Mono, perhaps) in order that you can test on your Windows box before deploying (unless you really just want to edit files on your Windows PC, in which case I'd ask: why?).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a cross compiler. A compiler that runs on machine A but compiles for machine b.
I suggest you try cygwin or mingw, which installs all the tools you need to compile for linux. All the system calls that relevant to linux are emulated.